# invalid expression error when using group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

- `Employee table` has two attributes.`(employee_ID (PK), office_id)`
- `Office table` has two attributes. `(office_id (PK), location)`.

I need number of employees for each office.

So I wrote the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(E.EMPLOYEE_ID), O.LOCATION
 FROM REALSTATE.EMPLOYEE AS E, REALSTATE.OFFICE AS O 
 WHERE E.OFFICE_ID=O.OFFICE_ID
 GROUP BY E.OFFICE_ID
```

I get the following error. " `Column reference 'O.LOCATION' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression`"

Comment: Presumably `REALESTATE.OFFICE` doesn't really have the column `LOCATION`.

Comment: `WHERE E.OFFICE` -> shouldn't this be `OFFICE_ID`?

Comment: yes.That is my bad. e.office is e.office_id

Answer (score 0):

When you do a GROUP BY, everything in the SELECT must be either an aggregate or in the GROUP BY. Move the COUNT and OFFICE_ID to a subquery and JOIN them back to your main table.

You'll have to check the field names, it looks like you're not quite consistent on OFFICE vs OFFICE_ID in EMPLOYEE, but this should do it for you.

```
SELECT ECount, O.LOCATION
FROM (SELECT COUNT(E.EMPLOYEE_ID) as ECount, E.OFFICE
      FROM REALSTATE.EMPLOYEE AS E
      GROUP BY OFFICE) as C
INNER JOIN REALSTATE.OFFICE AS O on C.OFFICE=O.OFFICE_ID
```

The basic premise is you build an intermediate table (C) that has the office ID and how many people are in it, and join that back to OFFICE to resolve the name of the office associated with that ID

EDIT: @Gordon is correct, of course, MySQL does allow the non-standard behavior, sorry for the red herring. But try running the part inside the parenthesis alone and get it running, then put it back into the whole query and get that running, and when that all works you can pare it back down to the shorter notation.

Comment: This is not true in MySQL.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: if I remember correctly there is an sql mode that strictly constraints mysql to behave "correctly".

Comment: @zerkms . . . The statement "When you do a GROUP BY, everything in the SELECT must be either an aggregate or in the GROUP BY" is false in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).  It is worth asking whether the OP is using MySQL in the strict SQL mode (or something similar).

Comment: While MySQL has `GROUP BY` extension, it's totally unreliable when non-grouped fields are included, thus, I just would not recommend to use that. Just write valid SQL would be enough. So, answer above has sense, but I'd add the point about mentioned `GROUP BY` extension and why it's bad